# iDangerous Swiper - Change content of swiper-slide onClick

Tags: onclick, swiper.js

Is it possible to change the content inside an individual swiper-slide onclick ?

I have sequentially numbered divs INSIDE each swiper-slide that are supposed to overlay an image when that individual div is clicked.  I know JS is getting a response because it does change other divs outside of the swiper container when clicked.

I have tried:

```
    document.getElementById('div6').innerHTML=...

    document.getElementById('img6').src=....

    $('div6').on('click',function() {
    document.getElementById('div6').innerHTML="<img id='img6'   
    src='overlay.png'>";
    });
```

but nothing changes inside the swiper-slide.  Here is my Swiper initialization in case that matters:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    freeMode: true,
    width:200,
    loop: true,
    loopedSlides:30
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul write click handler like this:

```
$('#div6').on('click',function() {
    $(this).html('<img id="img6" src="overlay.png">');
});
```